# Tangent vector to a point on the surface.

Tags: differential-geometry

Recently, I studied the intrinsic geometry of surfaces. Is tangent vector to a point on the surface something intrinsic? (In another word, is the tangent plane independent of the ambient space?) I guess it is intrinsic but I only need clarification.

Comment: Yes, there are intrinsic definitions; but it depends on what exactly you've seen.

Comment: Geometrically, it is intrinsic because the tangent plane has its own system of coordinates where it does not rely on R3 right?

Comment: You need to first define a tangent vector before defining a tangent plane, not the other way around. What I'm saying is that the concept of "tangent vector to a surface at a point" can be defined without any mention of any "ambient space embedding" of the given surface. Since the "tangent vector to a surface at a point" is an intrinsic concept, it follows that the "tangent space to a surface at a point" is also an intrinsic concept (because the tangent space is just the set of all tangent vectors)

Comment: Oh ok. So tangent vector can be defined without ambient space and picking two specific tangent vector (as a basis) forms a tangent plane, where that tangent plane also not defined using ambient space. Instead, it has its own system of coordinates, which is my basis of tangent vector, with origin at point $p$, am I right?

Comment: Not quite; you're skipping too many steps. Once you have defined a tangent vector; you define the tangent space as the set of all tangent vectors. You now have to show that the tangent space is in fact a vector space (i.e you can add tangent vectors and multiply by scalars). Once you have shown that the tangent space is itself a vector space, then you can start talking about a basis. In the case of a surface, the tangent space will be a 2-dimensional vector space; so yes, now you can choose $2$ basis vectors, and any other tangent vector can be written in terms of these

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Tangent vectors to a point on a manifold (or in particular a surface) are indeed intrinsic. An abstract manifold $M$ is a topological space which is Hausdorff, second countable, and locally homeomorphic to Euclidean space. If we want our manifold to be smooth, we have to specify which functions are smooth. We call the global smooth functions $\mathscr{C}^\infty(M)$.

Supposing we have these data, we can define abstractly the tangent space at a point $p\in M$ as follows. An operator $D:\mathscr{C}^\infty(M)\to \mathbb{R}$ is called a derivation of $\mathscr{C}^\infty(M)$ at $p$ if it is $\mathbb{R}-$linear and satisfies the following Leibniz rule: given $f,g\in \mathscr{C}^\infty(M)$, 
$$ D(fg)=D(f)g(x)+f(x)D(g).$$
The space of such derivations of $\mathscr{C}^\infty(M)$ at $p$ is called the tangent space of $M$ at $p$, and denoted $T_pM$.

Here is an example: if $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ (or any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n)$, then an example of a derivation at $p\in M$ is the partial derivative operator $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}|_p$. It turns out that a basis of $T_pM$ as described above is $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}|_p,\ldots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}|_p)$. This is canonically isomorphic to the naïve tangent space to $M$ at $p$ given by the "tangent directions." Indeed, one can see $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ as being the tangent direction pointing in the $x^i$ coordinate direction.

One can show in general that so-defined $T_pM$ is a vector space such that $\dim T_pM=\dim M$. Moreover, it has a basis consisting of partial derivative operators defined using the coordinate charts on the manifold. This is a valid and embedding-independent notion of tangent space for a manifold.

You can find on wikipedia another notion defined in terms of trajectories of curves.

Comment: For another definition defined in terms of trajectories of curves, is the tangent vector also independent of the ambient space?

Comment: Yes, that notion is also independent of embedding.

Comment: Last confirmation. The mapping is $dX_p:U\rightarrow T_pS$, so my tangent space is formed from this process and since it does not rely on the local chart, it is independent of embedding?

Comment: Can you explain what the symbols you have used above mean (i.e. what $X$ is etc.)

Comment: $X_p$ is my local chart at a point $p$ on my open set $U$, $dX_p$ is the differential map at point $p$.

Comment: How is the map $dX_p$ defined on $U$ (I assume $U$ is the domain of your chart).

Comment: Oh sorry, it should be the mapping of the tangent vectors in $\mathbb{R^2}$ to tangent vectors on the surface $S$

Comment: Well, your definition relies a priori on a chart and you need to show that it is independent of the chart, but yes the charts and this map are part of the manifold structure.

Comment: yes it is independent of the chart and thus with this definition, the tangent vector is independent of embedding.